# How to reduce sql query time when ORDER BY used

Tags: mysql, sql, yii

I have an app developed using `yii framework` and one of the queries takes too long.  Without the `criteria->order` operation it returns the data under 1 second.

The table has 1 million registrations. There are indexes on each columns.  The query is:

```
select *
 from village
 where map_type_id = 4 and status = 1
 order by last_update_resource asc
 limit 1

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `village` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `k` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `map_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `village_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nation_id` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_update` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_update_resource` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `verified` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_verification` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_update_points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `x` (`x`),
  KEY `y` (`y`),
  KEY `k` (`k`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `nation_id` (`nation_id`),
  KEY `last_update_resource` (`last_update_resource`),
  KEY `map_type_id` (`map_type_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `village_type_id` (`village_type_id`),
  KEY `last_update` (`last_update`),
  KEY `verified` (`verified`),
  KEY `last_verification` (`last_verification`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `points` (`points`),
  KEY `last_update_points` (`last_update_points`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1000001 ;
```

What can I do to get the requesttime to 1 second?

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->order = 'last_update_resource asc';
$criteria->limit = 1;

VillageSlaveM::$server_id = $world_id;
$model_village = VillageSlaveM::model()->findByAttributes(
        array(
    'map_type_id' => VillageM::$map_type_id['village'],
    'status' => VillageM::ACTIVE), $criteria
);
```

Comment: Is there an index on the sort column?

Comment: yes, i have 13 columns, and there is a index on each one

Comment: Can you show what the resulting query is?  It is easier to optimize from the MySQL perspective.

Comment: Show us a SQLFiddle of your schema please, including indexes.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: is this ok ? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8356a/1

Comment: Add an index on(map_type_id ,status,last_update_resource )

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bc6b/1

Comment: i think that you are right Mihai

Comment: Incearca si vezi ce iese.Also you have too many indices,if you do insert or updates this will slow them.

Comment: i need those indexes for many operations; this table has only updates

Comment: Mihai, post your response as answer, and i will accept it. 10x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a composite index on `(map_type_id ,status,last_update_resource )` to cover your where conditions.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bc6b/1